# how to capture the right click event using getMouse()

Tags: python, graphics

I am trying to use graphics.py to write a user graphics interface. The problem is that how can I capture the right click event? It seems that the function getMouse() could just returns where the  mouse was left-clicked as a Point object.

```
    from graphics import *
    def main():
        win = GraphWin("My Circle", 100, 100)
        c = Circle(Point(50,50), 10)
        c.draw(win)
        win.getMouse() # pause for click in window
        win.close()
     main()
```

I want to know how can I capture the right-click event in the window, thanks.

Comment: You should look at the source to graphics.py.  Adding a handler for mouse right-clicks would be pretty trivial.  graphics.py is simply Tkinter program.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you try [TkInter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) for a python GUI.

Here is an example that detects a right click:

```
from Tkinter import *


def showPosEvent(event):
    print 'Widget=%s X=%s Y=%s' % (event.widget, event.x, event.y)



def onRightClick(event):
    print 'Got right mouse button click:', 
    showPosEvent(event)


tkroot = Tk()
labelfont = ('courier', 20, 'bold')               
widget = Label(tkroot, text='Hello bind world')
widget.config(bg='red', font=labelfont)          
widget.config(height=5, width=20)                
widget.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

widget.bind('<Button-3>',  onRightClick)        


widget.focus()                                    
tkroot.title('Click Me')
tkroot.mainloop()
```