# How to detect right click in Python GUI?

Tags: python, minesweeper

I am making a minesweeper game in python with GUI. I want to use the right click of the mouse to flag a field on the GUI. I have a graphics.py library (give to me by my teacher) which has a function to detect left-clicks. How can I detect right click?
The function for detecting left-click is:

```
def getMouse(self):
    self.update()      # flush any prior clicks
    self.mouseX = None
    self.mouseY = None
    while self.mouseX == None or self.mouseY == None:
        self.update()
        if self.isClosed(): raise GraphicsError("getMouse in closed window")
        time.sleep(.1) # give up thread
    x,y = self.toWorld(self.mouseX, self.mouseY)
    self.mouseX = None
    self.mouseY = None
    return Point(x,y)
```

Point(x,y) will give me the click-coordinates.

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515929/how-to-capture-the-right-click-event-using-getmouse) has what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch MouseEvents, as described [here](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MouseEvent-class.html). You can follow the tutorial I've pasted from [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial)

The flags for the different mouse buttons are as follows: `wx.MOUSE_BTN_LEFT`
 `wx.MOUSE_BTN_MIDDLE` and `wx.MOUSE_BTN_RIGHT`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# mousegestures.py

import wx
import wx.lib.gestures as gest

class MyMouseGestures(wx.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 500))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        mg = gest.MouseGestures(panel, True, wx.MOUSE_BTN_LEFT)
        mg.SetGesturePen(wx.Colour(255, 0, 0), 2)
        mg.SetGesturesVisible(True)
        mg.AddGesture('DR', self.OnDownRight)

    def OnDownRight(self):
          self.Close()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyMouseGestures(None, -1, "mousegestures.py")
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Centre()
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Will definitely try this method. (Y)

Comment: @M_G Definitely hope it helps you out, at least in understanding how to use the specific mouse buttons. Fixed up the formatting too.